# How to set content field minimum height using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, templates

I'm creating a template using bootstrap and the content area is adjusting self according to contents inside it. and if there is less content text then footer and nav gets so closer like see this pic if there is no content text.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7uHT.jpg)

How can I set minimum height of content so that footer will stay on browser footer and there will be space for content between header and footer.

Comment: Can you please create fiddle...

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand. Can  you please explain with little more ?

Comment: Create demo of code using https://jsfiddle.net/ this link...

Answer (score 0):

You could use css like this to set the minimum height to that of the viewport:

`minimum-height: 100vh;`

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked :D was so easy. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is to make sticky footer when you are using bootstrap, add the class `footer` in footer wrapper and it will stick to the bottom.

Take a look at the example template provided by bootstrap

[Bootstrap sticky footer Template](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Comment: Thanks @Sanjeev, surely it will improve my knowledge while learning it.